# jQuery cannot detect click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp

This is a strange case. I have this JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ";
        path = /" + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : ";
        expires = " + exdate.toGMTString());
    }

    if (document.cookie.indexOf("eucookie") === -1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#eucookielaw").animate({
                height: '50px', 
                opacity: '0.9'
            }, "slow");
        }, 3000);
    }

    $("#removecookie").click(function () {
        SetCookie('eucookie', 'eucookie', 365 * 10);
        $("#eucookielaw").remove();
    });
</script>
```

Which is placed at the bottom of the page in footer file. HTML is this:

```
<div id="eucookielaw">
    <p>
        <?php echo $lang['use_cookies'];?>
        <a id="removecookie">
            <?php echo $lang['understand'];?>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

In the `head` of the page I am sending a JSONP request to a remote server and putting the results of the request in a `div` which is placed right before the closing body tag.

If I remove the remote request, `SetCookie()` works as intended but with the remote request it doesn't. I tried to alert the click event but it doesn't work either:

```
$("#removecookie").click(function ()
```

Please give me an idea what could cause this strange behavior? I checked for duplicated ids or similar problems - all is OK. Console is empty of errors but still the `onclick` event doesn't work.

I can not paste here the remote request code because it is very complicated and long if you ask me to do so. So any ideas what to check? Thanks!

Comment: Because you remove the container div (`$("#eucookielaw").remove();`) in `click` handler?

Comment: no, unfortunately remove() is after setting the coockie and non of the actions in the click event is not being executed.. Can not detect click event. that's the problem. Nothing in $("#removecookie").click(function () is executed !thanks

Comment: The quotes in your string concatenations are incorrect and will be causing syntax errors. You've said you checked the console, so I assume these are just typos in the question?

Comment: No problem with the quotes and no errors in the console. Which quotes you think are wrong\? If there are wrong quotes code wouldn't work when I remove the remote request..

Comment: The setters of `document.cookie`, `path` and `expires`. You can tell something is wrong from the syntax highlighting

Comment: if there is syntax error console would alert me and also the rest of the js on the page would stop working. In fact all other js on page is working.. and belive me there is a lot of js on the page.. I believe this is related to the remote request otherwise the code would not work in all cases..

Comment: How do you insert the new content from your JSONP request? If you happen to use something like `body.innerHTML += "some HTML code"`, that would destroy all event listeners on your body elements, as basically all these elements would be re-created.